# Calculated column formula not working when referring to a Yes/No type column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, modern-experience

I am working on a SharePoint list validation to automate some process.

I have **Column A which is a Yes/No type column** and I have **Column B which is a calculated column** that will take input from column A.

A simple example:

```
Column A | Column B
Yes      | 1
No       | 0
```

But when I use the formula for Column B as below the result is always 0:

```
=IF(ShipmentRequired="Yes",1,0)
```

It also shows the same result when I try to change the formula as below:

```
=IF(ShipmentRequired=1,1,0)
```

The result will always appear as 0 as it doesn't identify the input in Column A.

```
Column A | Column B
Yes      | 1
No       | 0
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to rewrite your formula to:

```
=IF([ShipmentRequired],1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the fields are called Yes/No fields their values are actually Boolean (i.e. TRUE/ FALSE).

So you can use your formula like:

```
=IF([ShipmentRequired]=TRUE,1,0)
```

**OR** simply as Chris mentioned:

```
=IF([ShipmentRequired],1,0)
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Return your calculated field as **Number**.

**official documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).

Comment: Hi @Nas, Does this answers your question? If Yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.